# Delphi - Firebird - Vista access to socket denied

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, firebird

I am facing problem with my delphi application connecting to firebird database on Port 45000:
If I try to connect as Localhost/45000:C:\DBNAME.fdb its giving below error

Can't format message 13:98 -- message file C:\firebird.msg not found. Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". Failed to establish a connection. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

I don't understand what is this error tried changing port cheked free ports using netstat command no use.

Any help will be highly appreciated 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure that's the best location to store your database file?

Comment: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq288/

Comment: Also check this [FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq136/), which is specific to your problem.

Comment: Is Firebird actually running on port 45000 on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same problem in the past.
Re-installing Firebird helped.

Comment: Yes I did turned off UAC,Firewall and Antivirus no use.

Comment: Reinstalling firebird also has no effect

Comment: Did you try to run the application on another computer?  Just to be sure that antiviruses or other protection software are not blocking the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Issue Sorted out.
Thanks to those who gave some suggestions.

It was **Windows One Care firewall** service which was blocking all the ports in the vista system.

I could not find it because it was visible only in the services and not anywhere else.

Comment: it is excellent to spend the time giving an answer, and not be considered on upvoting/accepting the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire [Configuring Firebird](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.ConfiguringFirebird). Create an alias of your database.

Also take a look on the [Installing Notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg25-installing.html). Add exception to the windows firewall. If still encountering problems take a look on the http://www.gradiencesupport.com/entries/20932048-Gradience-Pro-Enterprise-Unable-to-connect-to-your-Interbase-Firebird-Server